# Add new name from user form if not in list. Excel VBA

Tags: vba, list, search, addition, names

Hi I am relatively new to VBA but have managed to adapt some code and write a bit myself.

I now however have a problem. I have the below code that I found and adapted. I present a user form and the user inputs a name and other information.

The code searches the list of names and adds the other information alongside the name. Over writing what is already there. If I have a new user I have to add the name at the bottom and all continues to work well.

I was wondering if anyone here could see in the code where I need to add some lines so if the code dose not find the name in the list then if addes it at the bottom please?

```
Private Sub txtName_AfterUpdate()
  Dim intMyVal As String
  Dim lngLastRow As Long
  Dim strRowNoList As String

 intMyVal = txtName.Value 'Value to search for, change as required.
    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row 'Search Column AA, change as required.

    For Each cell In Range("AA4:AA" & lngLastRow) 'Starting cell is AA4, change as required.

      If cell.Value = intMyVal Then

        If strRowNoList = "" Then
             strRowNoList = strRowNoList & cell.Row
          Else
           strRowNoList = strRowNoList & ", " & cell.Row      
        End If

      End If

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for ?

Used a flag to check if found or not

```
Private Sub txtName_AfterUpdate()
  Dim intMyVal As String
  Dim lngLastRow As Long
  Dim strRowNoList As String
  Dim flg As Boolean

  intMyVal = txtName.Value 'Value to search for, change as required.
    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row 'Search Column AA, change as required.
    flg=False

    For Each cell In Range("AA4:AA" & lngLastRow) 'Starting cell is AA4, change as required.

      If cell.Value = intMyVal Then

        If strRowNoList = "" Then
             strRowNoList = strRowNoList & cell.Row
             flg=True
          Else
             strRowNoList = strRowNoList & ", " & cell.Row
              flg=True      
        End If

      End If


    Next cell
   if flg=False then Range("AA4:AA" & lngLastRow + 1) = txtName.value

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Newguy Thank you for your response. Unfortunately this is not working as Expected although perhaps a little closer than I had. Now if I enter a name on the user form in txtName that is in the list in AA then it clears all of the names out. If I enter a name that is not in the list AA then it replaces all of the names with the 1 I just entered plus 1 row (Which is the only 1 I wanted to add to). I am not sure if it is my fault for not explaining well. I only want to a the name from the user form to the bottom of the list in column AA if it is not already there if it is then do nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to understand your needs

Maybe they are these ones

```
Private Sub txtName_AfterUpdate()
  Dim myVal As String, strRowNoList As String
  Dim srchRng as Range 

  myVal = txtName.Value 'Value to search for, change as required.
  With Worksheets("MySheet") '<~~ change it as per your actual sheet name
    Set srchRng = .Range("AA4:AA" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row) 
    For Each cell In srchRng 
      If cell.Value = myVal Then strRowNoList = strRowNoList & cell.Row & ","
    Next cell

    If strRowNoList <> "" Then 
        strRowNoList = Left(strRowNoList, Len(strRowNoList) - 1)
    Else 
        strRowNoList = CStr(srchRng.Rows(srchRng.Rows.Count).Row + 1)
    End If 
  End With 
End Sub
```

But then I guess you have to pass `strRowNoList` to some routine that does the writing/overwriting.

Comment: I see now where My explanation has gone wrong.This is the after update in the txtName field from the user form. From here I am trying to work out if the name exists in the list that is held in AA. If it dose then carry on if it dose not then add it after the last row in AA. I then run the bulk of the routine again When More data is added to update the other fields. At that point the name exists and I find the row and add the other fields to it. My fault sorry. I will get back to you with the results once tested the above. Thank you fro your time and assistance.

Comment: I had an idea to approach this from another angle. The after update on the last field txtDirection does all the updates adding a record to 1 row starting at column A (this 1 is kept) and updating the row where the name occurs in the list starting at column AA, which is over written each time. This is directed by a case statement. All works if the name is there. So I added another Case for NEW and added an add name to the bottom of the list in AA.I need to change the code so it works because the name is not in AA not because I type NEW. If any one could help that would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I cannot add the code as it is to long is there a way to attach a text file?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone for their help and input. I worked out a way to do this using an error handler and although I do not think the solution is concise or pretty I have been able to make it work. I am sure some of the experts on here would be able to do the same in much less code if I could have explained my requirements clearer.

```
Private Sub txtDirection_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo MyerrorHandler:
Dim intMyVal As String
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim strRowNoList As String

intMyVal = txtName.Value 'Value to search for, change as required.
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row 'Search Column A, change as required.

For Each cell In Range("AA4:AA" & lngLastRow) 'Starting cell is F2, change as required.

    If cell.Value = intMyVal Then
        If strRowNoList = "" Then
            strRowNoList = strRowNoList & cell.Row
        Else
            strRowNoList = strRowNoList & ", " & cell.Row
        End If
    End If
Next cell

If txtDirection.Value <> "" Then
Ureg.txtDirection.SetFocus
Select Case txtDirection.Value 'If the user scans in
    Case "IN"
        Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
LastRow = ActiveCell.Row
Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Value = txtDate.Text
Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value = Time
Cells(LastRow + 1, 3).Value = txtName.Text
Cells(LastRow + 1, 4).Value = txtLocation.Text
Cells(LastRow + 1, 5).Value = Range("F1").Value
Cells(LastRow + 1, 6).Value = txtName.Text & txtLocation.Text
Cells(strRowNoList, 28).Value = txtDirection.Text
Cells(strRowNoList, 29).Value = txtDate.Text
Cells(strRowNoList, 30).Value = Time
Cells(strRowNoList, 31).Value = txtLocation.Text
Range("A2").Select
txtDate.Value = Date
txtName.Text = ""
txtLocation.Text = ""
txtDirection.Text = ""
Ureg.txtName.SetFocus

        Case "OUT" 'If the user scans OUT

 Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
LastRow = ActiveCell.Row
Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Value = txtDate.Text
Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value = Time
Cells(LastRow + 1, 3).Value = txtName.Text
Cells(LastRow + 1, 4).Value = txtLocation.Text
Cells(LastRow + 1, 5).Value = Range("F1").Value
Cells(strRowNoList, 28).Value = txtDirection.Text
Cells(strRowNoList, 29).Value = txtDate.Text
Cells(strRowNoList, 30).Value = Time
Cells(strRowNoList, 31).Value = txtLocation.Text
Cells(LastRow + 1, 6).Value = txtName.Text & txtLocation.Text
Range("H2").Select
txtDate.Value = Date
txtName.Text = ""
txtLocation.Text = ""
txtDirection.Text = ""
Ureg.txtName.SetFocus

        Case "NEW"  'Extra code if the user is set up as a NEW person No longer needed if the erro handler works.
 Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
LastRow = ActiveCell.Row
Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Value = txtDate.Text
Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value = Time
Cells(LastRow + 1, 3).Value = txtName.Text
Cells(LastRow + 1, 4).Value = txtLocation.Text
Cells(LastRow + 1, 5).Value = Range("F1").Value
Cells(lngLastRow + 1, 31).Value = txtName.Text
Cells(lngLastRow + 1, 32).Value = "IN"
Cells(lngLastRow + 1, 33).Value = txtDate.Text
Cells(lngLastRow + 1, 34).Value = Time
Cells(lngLastRow + 1, 35).Value = txtLocation.Text
Cells(LastRow + 1, 6).Value = txtName.Text & txtLocation.Text
Range("H2").Select
txtDate.Value = Date
txtName.Text = ""
txtLocation.Text = ""
txtDirection.Text = ""
Ureg.txtName.SetFocus

        Case Else 'Message if the user scannes something other than in , out or new.
            'MsgBox "Please enter either IN or OUT"
                Dim AckTime As Integer, InfoBox As Object
    Set InfoBox = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    'Set the message box to close after 10 seconds
    AckTime = 5
    Select Case InfoBox.Popup("Please enter either IN or OUT. Please try again.                                                         (This window will close automatically                                                                  after 5 seconds).", _
    AckTime, "Inccorect Destination Scanned", 0)
        Case 1, -1
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    End Select
    End If
    With ActiveWorkbook
   .SaveCopyAs .Path & "\" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "-" & [A1] & ".xlsm" 'This will save the sheet evertime a user scan is complete.

    'MsgBox strRowNoList
    End With
'End Sub

MyerrorHandler: 'This adds the name of the uses to the list in AA if they are not there already and then finishes the same code as above for a booking in. No new user should be scanning out.
If Err.Number = 13 Then
Cells(lngLastRow + 1, 27).Value = txtName.Text
Cells(lngLastRow + 1, 28).Value = "IN"
Cells(lngLastRow + 1, 29).Value = txtDate.Text
Cells(lngLastRow + 1, 30).Value = Time
Cells(lngLastRow + 1, 31).Value = txtLocation.Text
Range("H2").Select
txtDate.Value = Date
txtName.Text = ""
txtLocation.Text = ""
txtDirection.Text = ""
Ureg.txtName.SetFocus
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks once again to all,